# Running PowerShell script in Windows Task. Task starts but doesn't complete

Tags: postgresql, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm running a PowerShell script in a Windows Task. The PS script is running a PostGres command.  The Postgres command has an error early on, but then  Here's what I'm seeing:

- When I run the PS script standalone, I get an error at the top, but then does complete.  I get the expected result.
- When I run the PS Script via the Windows Task Scheduler, I get the expected result.  However, when I open up the Task History, I only see "Action Started" rather than "Action Started"...."Action Completed".  This seems to be a problem, because the task never seems to run again.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: What is the text for the Action that is being run? i.e. using Task scheduler you need to launch it via PowerShell.exe

Comment: The Action text is:  Task Scheduler launched action "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE" in instance "{b2197200-9f61-436d-82db-483579f1eb36}" of task "\Backup Riker Database SCHEDULED TASK".

Comment: But the text in the command is: powershell -f C:\X\backup_database.ps1

Comment: It could be that the script is waiting for using input. I'd try passing `-NoProfile` and `-NonInteractive` to see if it helps any

Comment: Try running a simple script first. i.e. `Write-host "a"` that you know will run. Test your execution string in a command prompt to see if you run into any errors. Also check your `-ExecutionPolicy` as you may have to bypass that as well.

Comment: @HAL9256 - ExecutionPolicy is "Unrestricted".  In terms of your other suggestion, the error I'm getting is very much a PostGres error.  Normal scripts are running fine.  That said, I will try a simple script and make sure I see "Task Completed" in Windows Scheduler.